# How to align text and images with on click of an image in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/866bh6du/embedded/result/) which I have replicated by seeing the screenshot below:

[image]

The screenshot and the fiddle is working in a way that if **I hit on any of the items above the following changes happen**:

1. Background-color changes into green.
2. Icons and Text turn into white.

The sample JQuery code which I have used in order to make that happen are:

```
$("#franchisehub").click(function() {
  if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.arrow-down').css('display', 'none');
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');
    $('#franchisehub img.black').css('display', 'none');

  } else {
    resetAll();
    $('#franchisehub').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'white');
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex');
    $('#franchisehub img.black').css('display', 'none');
    $('#franchisehub img.white').css('display', 'inline-block');

  }

});
```

**Problem Statement:**

In the fiddle, when I hit on any of the items, the text **(present in the square box)** comes towards the center of the box and **whereas when its not being clicked it comes outside of the square box (which I don't want to happen)**.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the fiddle so that when the items are being clicked and when the items are not being clicked, it should remain at the same position.

Comment: It seems that both images are showing when a box is not selected, which pushes the text down. What is in your `resetAll()` function? Also, I'd suggest using more general selectors so you don't need to repeat yourself. See [DRY @ jQuery.com](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/dont-repeat-yourself/).

Comment: @showdev In order to make my code modular, I have used resetAll() function so that I don't have to write of lines of code.  

Yes, two images get displayed, when its clicked white gets displayed and when its not clicked black gets displayed.

Comment: What I mean is that *both* images are showing when a box is not selected. I assume you want to toggle between the two images.

Comment: @showdev is right. You should hide the second image, then show it when you click.

Comment: @DaleNguyen Is there any way, we can do with the current code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long answer, so I put it here.

In the original CSS, you should hide the second image in the first place

```
.white{
 display: none;
}
```

Then, in the script, you can hide the .black when you click:

```
 $("#franchisehub").click(function() {
      if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
        $('.arrow-down').css('display', 'none');
        $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');
        $('#franchisehub img.white').css('display', 'inline-block');   
        $('#franchisehub img.black').css('display', 'none');

      } else {
        resetAll();
        $('#franchisehub').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('#franchisehub p').css('color', 'white');
        $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex');
        $('#franchisehub img.black').css('display', 'none');
        $('#franchisehub img.white').css('display', 'inline-block');

      }
```

Inside your resetAll(), you should have this too:

```
  $('#franchisehub img.black').css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('#franchisehub img.white').css('display', 'none');
```

But your code has so many repetitions, you should find a way to reduce the amount of code. This function should be shortened by a lot! https://jsfiddle.net/866bh6du/1/

Comment: The text seems to go down again after click.

Comment: I cannot do everything for you, just take a look at the first box!

Comment: It's ok. You can apply the fix to the other boxes, and find a way to make your code clean if possible.

Comment: I cleaned my css a lot. Haven't got time to clean jquery and html codes. Will do soon.

Comment: I have used your code everywhere in the fiddle. It looks good now. Thanks for the help. I have one more quick question. In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekjrqnfd/embedded/result/) when the page loads, I just want the 2nd square box to have white cloud image. At this moment, it is take black cloud image on load.

Comment: You just to need set the original CSS for your second box, and it'll be good. 

#cloudbasedmobile .white{
  display: inline-block;
}

#cloudbasedmobile .black{
  display: none;
}

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661303/how-to-horizontally-scroll-the-contents-in-mobile-tablet-view-in-html-css). I am wondering if you can help me out or can give me a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Both images are showing when a box is not selected, which pushes the text down.
Also, I recommend not using inline CSS styles and using more general selectors to keep it [DRY](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/dont-repeat-yourself/).

Here's an example:

```js
jQuery('.product').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.product-all-contents {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.product-contents {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product-contents .product {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
}

.product.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.product img.white {
  display: none;
}
.product img.black {
  display: block;
}

.product.selected img.white {
  display: block;
}
.product.selected img.black {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-all-contents">
  <div class="product-contents">
    <div class="product" id="franchisehub">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Franchise-Hub.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/franchise-hub-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">

      <p>Franchise Hub</p>
    </div>

    <div class="product" id="cloudbasedmobile">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cloud-grey.png" alt="" width="70" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8042" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cloud-based-mobile-white.png" alt="" width="70" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8042" />

      <p>Cloud Based & Mobile</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="businessanalytics">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/business-analytics.png" alt="" width="53" height="53" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7949" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/business-analytics-white.png" alt="" width="53" height="53" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7949" />

      <p>Business Analytics</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="techsupport">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/tech-support.png" alt="" width="54" height="54" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7953" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/tech-support-white.png" alt="" width="54" height="54" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7953" />

      <p>Tech Support</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="ordermanagement">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/order-management.png" alt="" width="43" height="52" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7952" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/order-management-white.png" alt="" width="43" height="52" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7952" />

      <p>Order Management</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="employeemanagement">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/employee-management.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/employee-management-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
      <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-left: 5%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">Employee Management</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="whitelabel">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/white-label.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/white-label-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
      <p>White Label</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-contents">
    <div class="product" id="brandcontrol">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/brand-control.png" alt="" width="57" height="57" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7956" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/brand-control-white.png" alt="" width="57" height="57" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7956" />

      <p>Brand Control</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="leadtracking">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/lead-tracking.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7957" />
      <img class="white" style="display:none;" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/lead-tracking-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7957" />

      <p>Lead Tracking &amp; CRM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="custominvoicing">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/custom-invoicing.png" alt="" width="51" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7958" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/custom-invoicing-white.png" alt="" width="51" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7958" />

      <p>Custom Invoicing</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="goalsetting">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/goal-setting.png" alt="" width="50" height="51" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7959" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/goal-setting-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="51" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7959" />

      <p>Goal Setting</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="customizationtools">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/customization-tools.png" alt="" width="54" height="53" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7960" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/customization-tools-white.png" alt="" width="54" height="53" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7960" />

      <p>Customization Tools</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="royaltycalculator">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/royalty-calculator.png" alt="" width="50" height="51" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7961" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/royalty-calculator-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="51" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7961" />

      <p>Royalty Calculator</p>
    </div>
    <div class="product" id="emailmarketing">
      <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/email-marketing.png" alt="" width="51" height="52" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7962" />
      <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/email-marketing-white.png" alt="" width="51" height="52" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7962" />

      <p>Email Marketing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Just for fun, here's an example with pure CSS and no jQuery:

```css
.product-all-contents {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.product-contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-contents label {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
}

.product {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 3px solid rgb(145, 147, 150);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product img.white {
  display: none;
}
.product img.black {
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggler {
  display: none;
}

.toggler:checked+.product {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.toggler:checked+.product img.white {
  display: inline-block;
  ;
}
.toggler:checked+.product img.black {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-all-contents">
  <div class="product-contents">

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Franchise-Hub.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/franchise-hub-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <p>Franchise Hub</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cloud-grey.png" alt="" width="70" height="50">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cloud-based-mobile-white.png" alt="" width="70" height="50">
        <p>Cloud Based &amp; Mobile</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/business-analytics.png" alt="" width="53" height="53">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/business-analytics-white.png" alt="" width="53" height="53">
        <p>Business Analytics</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/tech-support.png" alt="" width="54" height="54">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/tech-support-white.png" alt="" width="54" height="54">
        <p>Tech Support</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/order-management.png" alt="" width="43" height="52">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/order-management-white.png" alt="" width="43" height="52">
        <p>Order Management</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/employee-management.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/employee-management-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <p>Employee Management</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/white-label.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/white-label-white.png" alt="" width="59" height="59">
        <p>White Label</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/brand-control.png" alt="" width="57" height="57">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/brand-control-white.png" alt="" width="57" height="57">

        <p>Brand Control</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/lead-tracking.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        <img class="white" style="display:none;" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/lead-tracking-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        <p>Lead Tracking &amp; CRM</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/custom-invoicing.png" alt="" width="51" height="50">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/custom-invoicing-white.png" alt="" width="51" height="50">
        <p>Custom Invoicing</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/goal-setting.png" alt="" width="50" height="51">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/goal-setting-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="51">
        <p>Goal Setting</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/customization-tools.png" alt="" width="54" height="53">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/customization-tools-white.png" alt="" width="54" height="53">
        <p>Customization Tools</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>    
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/royalty-calculator.png" alt="" width="50" height="51">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/royalty-calculator-white.png" alt="" width="50" height="51">
        <p>Royalty Calculator</p>
      </div>
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
      <div class="product">
        <img class="black" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/email-marketing.png" alt="" width="51" height="52">
        <img class="white" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/email-marketing-white.png" alt="" width="51" height="52">
        <p>Email Marketing</p>
      </div>
    </label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks good now. You gave me the weekend project. Will try to use toggle class to see how it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

If you can share the HTML code then it would be great, anyways here is how you can achieve this in a simple way...

```js
$(".main-div").on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  $(this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-div">
  Some text
</div>
<div class="main-div">
  Some text
</div>
<div class="main-div">
  Some text
</div>
```